# Input remain "onfocus" after first selection

Tags: jquery, html

Hi im building a form where in php i already know the email of the user.. So i insert it as value "in gray" if you select the input with the mouse. it became black "active". but then if you select something else, it became gray again.. obviously cause its not in focus anymore..

but how can i preserve the black color after the user select this for just one time.. so it dosent became gray again. thanks

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BAes7/

Here is my code

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="mail@gmail.com" size="22" onblur="if(this.value == 'mail@gmail.com') { this.style.color='#ccc'; this.value='mail@gmail.com'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'mail@gmail.com') {this.style.color='#000'; this.style.fontStyle='normal'; this.value='mail@gmail.com'}" class="textBox" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204); font-style: normal;">
```

Comment: Are you looking for `placeholder`....? http://jsfiddle.net/cH8Dq/

Comment: sorry never heard of that before, really sorry is that for? i will search thanks

Comment: @MonchoChavez just add in your input tag `placeholder="email"`

Comment: Thanks but it dosent became black on active, and remain like that after selection.. how do i do that, css? how?

Comment: So... before the input ever has focus, it should be grey text.  If the input has focus, it should be black text.  Once the input has had focus and then lost it, the text should now remain black for the rest of the time, regardless of having focus or not.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes once it became black, even if you click outside or somewhere else, the text remain black.. it is just gray if you do not clic on it.. :)

Comment: @MonchoChavez Almost positive you would need JS for that then.

Comment: I was almost sure also.. i just dont know how.

Comment: Hey... that code up there, it works...?  It only turns grey again if the value is still equal to the person's email address.  Was that up there the whole time?  lol.... I didn't read it.  **To modify the code you have up top** all you have to do is remove the `onBlur` part and it will also do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: ohh, I thought JS/JQuery was assumed.  I used JQuery.  Let me see if I can find a straight JS solution for you (if you need it?).

```
<input id="special_text_box" name="special_text_box" type="text" value="hello world"></input>


<style>
#special_text_box {color:#C0C0C0}
</style>

<script>

$("#special_text_box").on('focusin',function(){
   $(this).css('color','#000000'); 
});

</script>
```

k... pure JS:

```
<input type="text" value="hello world" style="color:#C0C0C0" 
             onfocus="this.style.color='#000000'"></input>
```